# How do I use JavaScript to show a spinner while my server side code completes operations?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

I am building a flask app where a users input is collected via a form (#questions) and submitted via post. Once received by the server the template is to be rendered again with a list of the users input.

Eventually I would like to build out some functions that incorporate more complex operations on the server side that will take more time. For that reason I want to create a UI where a spinner shows on form submission until the server side renders the page again with the result to inform the user the app is working. As I understand it, there is no way to modify a page after the form has been submitted. I tried to add an event listener to the "Submit" button to show the spinner originally, but the form would be sent first before showing so it wouldn't work.

I did some research into alternative methods and thought that using Javascript to delay the form submission until the spinner had been shown could be a good solution. That's what I am trying to do with the function in the  tag below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Security Policy Generator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='output.css') }}" />
 <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.querySelector('#questions').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    document.querySelector('#spinner').style.visibility = 'visible';
    

    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("questions"));

    httpRequest.open('POST', '/', true);
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (httpRequest.redyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
        document.querySelector('#spinner').style.visibility = 'invisible';
      }
    };
    httpRequest.send(formData);
    console.log('success');

    return false;
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body class="bg-black">
  <div class='bg-center bg-white py-8 px-6 shadow rounded-lg sm:px-10 mx-auto max-w-screen-xl text-center bg-no-repeat bg-blend-multiply' >
    <h1 class="mb-4 text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900 dark:text-black md:text-5xl lg:text-6xl"><span class="text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r to-emerald-600 from-sky-400">AI Powered</span> Security Policy Generator</h1>
    <form id="questions" class='mb-0 space-y-6' action="/" method="POST">
      <label class="float-left text-gray-700" htmlFor="business-name">Enter business name:</label>
      <input class='w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-lg
      shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring
      focus:ring-indigo-500 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700'
        type="text" name="business-name" placeholder="Name of organization" required />
      <div>
        <label class='float-left text-gray-700' htmlFor="dropdown">Select your industry:</label>
        <select class='w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-lg
        shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring
      focus:ring-indigo-500 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700'
      id="dropdown" name="industry" required></selectid>>
          <option value="">-- Select --</option>
          <option value="utilities">Utilities</option>
          <option value="real estate">Real Estate</option>
          <option value="healthcare">Healthcare</option>
          <option value="gaming-hospo">Gaming & Hospitality</option>
          <option value="insurance">Insurance</option>
          <option value="education">Education</option>
          <option value="non-profit">Non-profit</option>
          <option value="professional">Professional services</option>
      </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="float-left text-gray-700" htmlFor="dropdown">Select your desired framework:</label>
            <select class='w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-lg
            shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring
            focus:ring-indigo-500 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700'
            id="dropdown" name="framework" required >
              <option value="">-- Select --</option>
              <option value="NIST">NIST</option>
              <option value="HIPAA">HIPAA</option>
              <option value="SOC2">SOC2</option>
              <option value="CIS-controls">CIS Controls</option>
              <option value="COBIT">COBIT</option>
              <option value="ISO27000">ISO27000</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      
      <h3 class="text-left text-gray-700">What type of policy would you like to create?</h3>
      <div class="text-left">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="Acceptable Use" required/>
        <label class="text-gray-700 px-2">
            Acceptable Use
        </label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="Security Awareness Training"/>
        <label class="text-gray-700 px-2">
          Security Awareness & Training
        </label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="Change Management"/>
        <label class="text-gray-700 px-2">
            Change Management
        </label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="Incident Response"/>
        <label class="text-gray-700 px-2">
          Incident Response
        </label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="Option" value="Remote Access"/>
        <label class="text-gray-700 px-2">
          Remote Access
        </label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="Network Security"/>
        <label class="text-gray-700 px-2">
          Network Security
        </label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="Data Retention"/>
        <label class="text-gray-700 px-2">
          Data Retention
        </label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="Access Management"/>
        <label class="text-gray-700 px-2">
          Access Management
        </label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="Password Management"/>
        <label class="text-gray-700 px-2">
          Password Management
        </label><br>
      </div>
      <input class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-indigo-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border border-indigo-500 rounded" type="submit" value="Submit" />
      <div id="spinner" class="invisible" role="status">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="inline w-8 h-8 mr-2 text-gray-200 animate-spin dark:text-gray-600 fill-red-600" viewBox="0 0 100 101" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M100 50.5908C100 78.2051 77.6142 100.591 50 100.591C22.3858 100.591 0 78.2051 0 50.5908C0 22.9766 22.3858 0.59082 50 0.59082C77.6142 0.59082 100 22.9766 100 50.5908ZM9.08144 50.5908C9.08144 73.1895 27.4013 91.5094 50 91.5094C72.5987 91.5094 90.9186 73.1895 90.9186 50.5908C90.9186 27.9921 72.5987 9.67226 50 9.67226C27.4013 9.67226 9.08144 27.9921 9.08144 50.5908Z" fill="currentColor"/>
            <path d="M93.9676 39.0409C96.393 38.4038 97.8624 35.9116 97.0079 33.5539C95.2932 28.8227 92.871 24.3692 89.8167 20.348C85.8452 15.1192 80.8826 10.7238 75.2124 7.41289C69.5422 4.10194 63.2754 1.94025 56.7698 1.05124C51.7666 0.367541 46.6976 0.446843 41.7345 1.27873C39.2613 1.69328 37.813 4.19778 38.4501 6.62326C39.0873 9.04874 41.5694 10.4717 44.0505 10.1071C47.8511 9.54855 51.7191 9.52689 55.5402 10.0491C60.8642 10.7766 65.9928 12.5457 70.6331 15.2552C75.2735 17.9648 79.3347 21.5619 82.5849 25.841C84.9175 28.9121 86.7997 32.2913 88.1811 35.8758C89.083 38.2158 91.5421 39.6781 93.9676 39.0409Z" fill="currentFill"/>
        </svg>
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  {% if result %}
  <div class='bg-white py-8 px-6 shadow rounded-lg sm:px-10 mx-auto max-w-screen-xl text-left'>
    <textarea class='result w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-lg
        shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring
        focus:ring-indigo-500 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700' readOnly='True'>{{ result }}</textarea> 
  </div>
  {% endif %}
</body>`
```

It is able to show the spinner, there are no errors in the console, however it seems to be preventing the page from being rendered again with the result in the textarea as required. The app logic works well if the  tag is commented out and the page gets rendered again with the result, but then I can't show the spinner. Here is my server side code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route("/", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        policy_type = request.form['option']
        industry = request.form['industry']
        business_name = request.form["business-name"]
        framework = request.form['framework']
        result = [policy_type, industry, business_name, framework]
        return render_template('index.html', result=result)
    
    result = request.args.get('result')
    return render_template('index.html',  result=result)
```

I am new to JavaScript so I'm sure I am missing some logic. I'm just not sure what it is. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using AJAX, the page is not automatically re-rendered. This technique is primarily used to update partial areas of the page without having to reload and render the entire page. The update must be done by your code as soon as the data has been received from the server.

This is a simple example using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), should the data be sent as text from the server. An adaptation for the JSON format is also easily possible. For both variants, the textarea should be permanently visible and not dependent on a condition. Furthermore, you don't need to render and send the entire template. In your case, you will probably want to use `jsonify` server-side to send the list in JSON format. Then you should use `resp.json()` instead of `resp.text()` in JavaScript for the response.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('#questions').addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.querySelector('#spinner').style.visibility = 'visible';
        const resp = await fetch('/', {
            method: 'POST', 
            body: new FormData(this)
        });
        resp.ok && (document.querySelector('textarea').value = await resp.text());
        document.querySelector('#spinner').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    });
});
```

You can also show the loading indicator without using AJAX. In this case, the form is submitted as usual after the submit event has been caught and the visibility of the indicator has been changed. With some browsers, however, this must be awaited before the form data is sent. Depending on how long the task is taking, this may be a workaround.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('#questions').addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            document.querySelector('#spinner').style.visibility = 'visible';
            resolve();
        });
        this.submit();
    });
});
```

However, longer-lasting tasks are a broader topic. Processing with Celery is particularly useful if these are to be executed in the background. This is beyond the scope here and I recommend [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask) article to you.

Comment: Thanks so much! This answer is so detailed and helpful. I appreciate the extra articles too, they really help me to broaden my understanding.